# Given Orthocenter of a triangle and length of three segments, need to find area.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

Let, $O$ be an orthocenter of the triangle $\triangle ABC$, where $AO = 7, AB = 9, CO = 4$. Find the combined area of the triangles $\triangle AOC$ and $\triangle AOB$. Options given are $7\sqrt{3}, 14\sqrt{3}, 21\sqrt{3}, 28\sqrt{3}$.

I started off by assigning $AE =x$. Observing $\Delta AOE$, I can say $OE = \sqrt{49-x^2}$.
Then, $BE = 9-x$ and $OB = \sqrt{130-18x}$. Furthermore, $BC$ would be $\sqrt{146+8\sqrt{49-x^2}}$. But not sure if I'm going in right direction.

Comment: Are you sure these are all of equalities from the problem statement? I did some experimenting in Geogebra and it's not looking like we have one definite answer.

Comment: By the way, $AB^2 + CO^2 = AO^2 + BC^2 (= AE^2+EC^2+EO^2+EB^2)$, so you can calculate $BC$.

Comment: @radekzak There is one definite answer for sum of given area. As you have rightly mentioned, you can calculate $BC$. Now if $BC$ is known and so is $AO$, the sum of area of those two triangles is definite.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I probably had done some mistake in my drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\triangle=[AOB]+[AOC]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot BC\cdot AO$$

So we need to find $BC=a$

We use the fact that perpendicular bisector from circumcenter to any side is half the length of segment joining the opposite vertex to the orthocenter.

In the diagram below, not to scale, we see that

[image]

$$\left( \frac{c}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{OC}{2} \right)^2 = R^2 = \left( \frac{a}{2} \right)^2 +\left( \frac{AO}{2} \right)^2 $$
$$\Rightarrow a^2 = 4^2+9^2-7^2=48$$
$$\therefore \triangle=14\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: You missed the diagram :)

Comment: Haha, just added :D

Comment: Clean straightforward solution! :)